# Best encoding specifications for ondemand video on iPhone

Tags: iphone

My application plays ondemand streaming videos which is h264 and aac on iPhone OS 2.2.1+ / 3.1.2
I would like to know best settings for the encoder.

What H264 Profile ?
AAC v1 or V2 ?
Max bitrate.

Thanks for your advice guys.

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

If you look here: http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html

You will see the following:

Video formats supported:

H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;

H.264 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 3.0 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;

MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats